# Java Reading xml file error, file not found

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Im having the following problem reading an xml file, when using the dirFile below, i get the following error:

C:\Folder\folder1\folder2\project\resources\xmls\file.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

and the file is there and the path mentioned is correct. But if I use this path were it used to be C:\repo\eclipse\testcases\file.xml works. I want to have the xml inside the project.

```
private static String dirFile = "resources/xmls/";

DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(dirFile + file);
```

Any help woul dbe appreciated.

Comment: If the error is `C:\Folder\folder1\folder2\project\resources\xmls\file.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)`, then you have no file at `C:\Folder\folder1\folder2\project\resources\xmls\file.xml`

Comment: I'd also consider a saner folder naming convention.

Comment: I guess DocumentBuilder.parse() method doesn't take the path as you expected. I am not sure how exactly it should be but if you use an absolutepath instead of a relative path, and if it works, then you should change the content of "dirFile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the error: `C:\Folder\folder1\folder2\project\resources\xmls\file.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)` this means one of 2 things:

1. The file does not exist on that path
2. The path your are using to locate the file is not correct.

You should double check the absolute path by going to the file in your explorer and right clicking on the file, and then go into the properties. Make sure all your directories are correct and in the correct order.

Comment: it was the absolute path, i needed to add src/main cant believe i missed that. Thanks.